# Weka J48 decision tree problem

Tags: data-mining, cart, weka

I have a CSV dataset which contains `mean` (Numeric), `spread` (Numeric), `review` (string), `class` (Nominal) attributes. When I run J48 Decision tree with this dataset in Weka I get 100% accuracy even after cross validation (20 folds), and I believe this is wrong. So I converted all numeric attributes to binary attributes and run again my classifier which gave me 96% accuracy.

My question is why even after cross validation J48 gives 100% accuracy and what is binary attribute in Weka? Is my data set is wrong ?

Comment: What is that string attribute and what are you doing with it?